# Regex that match 50GB or less

Tags: regex

So, I found this regex to keep files 50 GB or less:

```
[5-9]\d\.\d{2,}\s*GB|\d{3,}\.\d{2,}\s*GB|\d{1,}\.\d{2,} \s*TB
```

It wasn't working for me so, I modified it to this:

```
[5-9]\d\.\d+\s*GB|\d{3,}\.\d+\s*GB|\d+\.\d+\s*TB
```

Now this is partially what I want and I've tested it with the following samples:

19 GB - Passes

19.0 GB - Passes

50 GB - Passes, but it shouldn't

50.0 GB - matches

61 GB - Passes, but it shouldn't

61.8 GB - matches

5TB - Passes, but it shouldn't

5.0 TB - matches

I've made other mods to capture integer, but then if I have a number like 8.65 GB, it get flagged. So, I'm stuck, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you explain your Q title and this: *"50 GB - Passes, but it shouldn't"*?

Comment: Where do you want to use it? Maybe it's easier to capture the number and deal with it in the program!

Comment: _"to keep files 50 GB"_ Where are you getting this data (the file size) from? And is there a reason you can't use the file size as a numeric value as suggested by csabinho?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I only want to choose a file if it's size less 50 GB or less. The file size can be listed as 40 GB or 30.51 GB. With the regex I have a file that has it's size listed as 60 GB would pass, but if it were listed as 60.0 GB it wouldn't.

Comment: @csabinho I'm reading it in the description and I've listed a few examples of how the file size would be in the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`([^\.][5-9]\d GB|[5-9]\d\.\d+\s*GB|\d{3,}\.\d+\s*GB|\d+(\.\d+\s*)?TB)` should be exactly what you want!

Comment: This has the same issue that I listed. For some reason, it will flag any file size with a decimal greater than 50 e.g. 7.50 GB. However, it does fix all the others listed!

Comment: Please check my updated regex! It works with your new test cases! And please update your test cases. I just checked the ones in your post!

Comment: @NuAlphaMan If you gave me the upvote, please accept my answer!

Answer (score 0):

This expression,

```
^([1-4]\d(?:\.\d+)?|[0-9](?:\.\d+)?|\.\d+)\s+gb$
```

might be close to what might be desired, or maybe just,

```
^([1-4]\d(?:\.\d+)?|[0-9](?:\.\d+)?)\s+gb$
```

and you can do the same for other units such at TB.

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/MBMnIL/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/MBMnIL/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: I've been using both regex101.com and regexr.com. They've help me get to what I listed. Yours is an approach I took before I listed my expression. The problem is that is would flag a file size like 6.85 GB and it shouldn't because it's less than 50 GB.